# quantaxis in docker can't be authenticated with localized mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker, authentication, pymongo

I have set user and password for local MongoDB, and I use QUANTAXIS (docker version).
It seems that certain containers can't be authenticated.
I have modified docker-compose.YAML, adding username:password to MongoDB URI, along with any other places where a URI is needed.
Still, the same error appears. Pymongo can't have authentication.

Comment: Hi @bomby9012, welcome to StackOverflow! Please be nice and provide some code you've tried, so people can help you easier. Could you describe your docker-compose YAML file? Have you tried to login into your MongoDB via prompt / command line?

Comment: - MONGODB=myUsername:myPassword@myIpAddress
and yes, I can login into my MongoDB via mongosh.